# Using facebook album images inside apps

Tags: facebook, image, gallery

Is it possible to show images made with a facebook app (which are uploaded by them to the users facebook gallery) inside another website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve images for the current user which she has uploaded with another app. The current user needs to be logged in with access token and you need

```
read_stream
user_photos
```

permissions.

You can retrieve urls to the photos with an FQL query and some client-side parsing:

First, query the FQL stream table for stream post attachments where the field "app_id" = the other app's id.

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND app_id=OTHER_APP_ID
```

This retrieves attachments for all posts done using the other app.

It's possible the query can be further narrowed down as follows, but I don't have a data set to test it on:

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND app_id=OTHER_APP_ID AND type=247
```

where 247 means photos. It could save you some work client-side (The two AND look hackish, perhaps someone can suggest a better statement...).

Once you have your response, parse the JSON. Each 'attachment' has a field called "media" which is an array. For each array item, check if type="photo". If it is, the "src" field will contain a url link to a small version of the uploaded photo.

To illustrate, here is the beginning of a sample JSON response:

```
"attachment": {
    "media": [
      {
        "type": "photo", 
        "src": "https://...._s.jpg", 
         //etc
```

The JSON response also contains links to other sizes.

For more information about the stream table please see the [Facebook Developers docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible but the users hae to give you authorization to acces their photos.

You can do this by getting extended permission:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();  

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
'req_perms' => 'user_photos' ));
```

Comment: I think he wants to be able to filter by his "app."